# How save image with canvas in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am creating an application for T-shirt customization in which I have put the canvas on image using CSS, but the problem is saving that image as canvas. `toDataURL` just gives part of the canvas area, but I want the whole image. There are other solutions on Stack Overflow but they do not solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: draw the whole on an a canvas? or first draw the background on a new canvas then the canvas on this new one.

Comment: it is image on which i have place the canvas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]
Hello, 
 you have to create an image object (tshirt) with a text object that holds the message.

1. to do that , load the image with **fabric.Image.fromURL()** function and inside the function , also create a text object that is going to show the tshirt message.
   so, your image and text belong to a group object.
2. every time you want to load new text , you call the **loadText** function and you change the text object.
3. i also added 4 buttons in order to manupulate up/down/left/right the text .
4. you can export the canvas + image+ text into the function **saveImg()**,
   but on the jsfiddle you will get a security message for **Tained canvases**.
   that happens because on the example i load the image from another domain and the code runs on another domain, you can run that code on your web application with no problem at all.
5. that is the code :

   ```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var scaleFactor=0.4

    canvas.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    canvas.renderAll();
    var myImg = 'http://izy.urweb.eu/files/tshirt.jpg';



    fabric.Image.fromURL(myImg, function(myImg) {
   var img1 = myImg.scale(scaleFactor).set({ left: 0, top: 0 });

   var text = new fabric.Text('the_text_sample\nand more', {
               fontFamily: 'Arial',
               fontSize:20,
           });

   text.set("top",myImg.height*scaleFactor-myImg.height*scaleFactor+150);
   text.set("left",myImg.width*scaleFactor/2-text.width/2);

   var group = new fabric.Group([ img1,text ], { left: 10, top: 10 });
   canvas.add(group);    
   });


   $('#loadText').on('click',loadText);
   $('#saveImg').on('click',saveImg);

   function loadText(){
     console.log($('#logo').val());
      canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].text = $('#logo').val();
      canvas.renderAll();
   }


   function saveImg(){    
   console.log('export image');
    if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
     alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
   }
   else {
     window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
   }
   }

   $('#left').on('click',function(){
   canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].set('left',canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].left-1);
   canvas.renderAll();
   })

   $('#right').on('click',function(){
   canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].set('left',canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].left+1);
   canvas.renderAll();
   })


   $('#top').on('click',function(){
   canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].set('top',canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].top-1);
   canvas.renderAll();
   })

   $('#bottom').on('click',function(){
   canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].set('top',canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].top+1);
   canvas.renderAll();
   })
   ```
6. that is the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/zrazuhcq/1/

hope helps, good luck.

Comment: This example doesn't seem to work when saving the image, it opens a blank window.

Comment: Same problem for me. This fiddle allows to download an image https://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/V6ufG/2/